# Libgdx - Input Processing [Android]. What am I not getting about Listeners?

Tags: java, android, input, libgdx, gesture

I've looked into numerous different ways to process input for android but I really can't get my head around it. I'm wondering with the code I provide you, could someone explain to me how I can integrate either approach into my code? and why it is appropriate to do so?

Firstly, I'll explain what my intentions are and show you a quick overview of the relevant code. I'm wanting to move my character, left, right and jump (for the time being). This is my first game, it's a portrait (somewhat similar context as Doodle Jump in regards to rendering) game without the automatic jumping. I'm got my level generated randomly, it renders all objects. Now I want to add input, but the main confusion is for me where do I put the code in my code?

Firstly, I have a `GameObject` class and a sub class `DynamicGameObject`, this is the `super` class for all objects inside the world (platforms, powerups, coins, player, enemies etc)

GameObject.java

```
public class GameObject {
    public final Vector2 position;
    public final Rectangle bounds;

    public GameObject (float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        this.position = new Vector2(x, y);
        this.bounds = new Rectangle(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height);
    }
```

DynamicGameObject.java

```
public class DynamicGameObject extends GameObject {
    protected static Vector2 velocity;
    public final Vector2 accel;

    public DynamicGameObject (float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        setVelocity(new Vector2());
        accel = new Vector2();
    }

    public Vector2 getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
}

public void setVelocity(Vector2 velocity) {
    DynamicGameObject.velocity = velocity;
}
}
```

And then I have the main game object in which will be moving upon the actions I'll implement. In this class would I be putting any input processing?

Ruben. java [relevant code]

```
public Ruben (float x, float y) {
    super(x, y, RUBEN_WIDTH, RUBEN_HEIGHT);
    state = RUBEN_STATE_IDLE;
    stateTime = 0;
    grounded = true;
    facingRight = true;
    }

public void update (float deltaTime) {
    //getVelocity().add(World.gravity.x * deltaTime, World.gravity.y * deltaTime);
    position.add(velocity.x * deltaTime, velocity.y * deltaTime);
    bounds.x = position.x - bounds.width / 2;
    bounds.y = position.y - bounds.height / 2;

    if (position.x < 0) position.x = World.WORLD_WIDTH;
    if (position.x > World.WORLD_WIDTH) position.x = 0;
    stateTime += deltaTime;
}
```

Then I have the world class that will update everything inside the game, The relevant update method will be where ruben gets updated, shown here:

```
private void updateRuben (float deltaTime, float accelX) {


    if (ruben.getState() != Ruben.RUBEN_STATE_IDLE && ruben.position.y <= 0.5f) ruben.hitPlatform();
    if (ruben.getState() != Ruben.RUBEN_STATE_IDLE) ruben.getVelocity().x = -accelX / 10 * Ruben.RUBEN_MOVE_VELOCITY;

    // clamp the velocity to the maximum, x-axis only
            if (Math.abs(ruben.getVelocity().x) > Ruben.RUBEN_MAX_VELOCITY) {
                ruben.getVelocity().x = Math.signum(ruben.getVelocity().x) * Ruben.RUBEN_MAX_VELOCITY;
            }

            // clamp the velocity to 0 if it's < 1, and set the state to standing
            if (Math.abs(ruben.getVelocity().x) < 1) {
                ruben.getVelocity().x = 0;
                if (Ruben.isGrounded()) {
                    Ruben.setState(Ruben.RUBEN_STATE_IDLE);
                }
            }

    ruben.getVelocity().scl(deltaTime);
    ruben.update(deltaTime);
    heightSoFar = Math.max(ruben.position.y, heightSoFar);
}
```

So Now i'm hoping you get the general context of the actor i'm dealing with, where would I go about putting a gesture listener callback? Do I put it into ruben? or do I create a seperate class altogether? I've tried out so many different ways and I'm not really getting anywhere it's abit frustrating. Where does the input handler go for the gestures? I tried putting the callback for a gesture detector with a new gesture listener inside the constructor of Ruben

```
(GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(new GestureHandler(this));
```

and then using a variable to indicate a fling has been directed upwards on the screen, when the boolean trigger is true, set the state of ruben to jump and change the velocity on y axis. It still didn't work. Can someone help?

if you need anything else, let me know.

Main game class

```
public class GameView extends Game {
    // used by all screens
    public SpriteBatch batcher;
    @Override
    public void create () {
        batcher = new SpriteBatch();
        Settings.load();
        Assets.loadBackgrounds();
        Assets.loadItems();
        Assets.loadRuben();
        setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an `InputAdapter` like the `GestureDetector` in libGdx you must set it, don't know if you do so, else there won't be any method called from the `GestureDetector`. Hope that's the main problem. [GestureDetector LibGdx Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gesture-detection)

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(new GestureHandler(this)));
```

Also if you want to use multiple InputAdapter you have to use an `InputMultiplexer` especially if you also want to use a Stage for GUI things. [Event Handling LibGdx Wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling)

```
    InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(new GestureHandler(this)));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```

**EDIT:**
My preferred way to implement it with a Screen is `MainMenuScreen extends Screen implements GestureDetector.GestureListener` and in the `show()` method `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(this));` then you have also easy access to the objects you want to control from the methods.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't what i'm looking for. I know what to implement. I just don't know where to implement it in my code, i've mentioned an attempt i've already made in the question with context around it hoping for suggestions or information on whether there are specific ways to implements the GestureListener.

Comment: Ok, I thought the inputs weren't recognized. How does your main class look like were you initialize the important stuff? What is the base class?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, i've adjusted the question.

Comment: do you mean the class inheriting everything or the class updating the main game?

Comment: My preferred way to implement it with a `Screen` is `MainMenuScreen extends Screen implements GestureDetector.GestureListener` and in the `show()` method `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new GestureDetector(this));`  then you have also easy access to the objects you want to control from the methods.

Comment: great advice, i'll give it a try and get back to you, for now. update your answer and i'll up-vote it, if it's correct i'll accept.

Comment: Thanks, hope it will fits your needs.